# HAProxy - ssl-hello-chk fails

Tags: debian, haproxy, high-availability, debian-stretch

I've been using the below config without any issues connecting to Apache running on Debian 8.  I just setup a couple new Debian 9 boxes with the same config settings, but now I'm getting: `Layer6 Invalid Response`

I've confirmed that traffic is flowing between the HAProxy box and the web nodes.  Does anyone have any idea why this check is failing? I've been digging through configuration files, and so far I haven't been able to find anything different between my systems.  My best guess is that it has something to do with Debian 9.

```
frontend web3_ssl_frontend
    bind <ipv4>:443
    bind <ipv6>:443
    mode tcp
    default_backend web3_ssl_backend

backend web3_ssl_backend
    balance roundrobin
    mode tcp
    cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
    default-server inter 4s rise 3 fall 2
    fullconn 20000
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https if { ssl_fc }

    option ssl-hello-chk
    server web1 192.168.163.2:443 maxconn 10000 check
    server web2 192.168.163.3:443 maxconn 10000 check
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ssl-hello-chk` uses sslv3 which is disabled on debian 9. You can use `tcp-check` instead.